# Microsoft VBA - error message subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I just got an old excel file with several macros. when I try to work with it, I always get the error message "subscript out of range". I think the error lies within the following code but due to my limited knowledge of VBA I am not able to find it. Could you pls check the code below? Thanks a lot!

```
Sub MD1()
Dim sh As String
Dim ce As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim c As Double
Dim d As Double
Dim e As Double
Dim r As Integer

n = Sheets("setup").Range("c11")
sh = Sheets("setup").Range("c14")
ce = Sheets("setup").Range("c15")

For r = 3 To n + 3
Sheets(sh).Range(ce) = Sheets("MD1").Range("A" & r)
a = Sheets("setup").Range("F17")
b = Sheets("setup").Range("G17")
c = Sheets("setup").Range("H17")
d = Sheets("setup").Range("I17")
e = Sheets("setup").Range("J17")
Sheets("MD1").Range("B" & r) = a
Sheets("MD1").Range("C" & r) = b
Sheets("MD1").Range("D" & r) = c
Sheets("MD1").Range("E" & r) = d
Sheets("MD1").Range("F" & r) = e
Next
```

Comment: where does the error occur (the line should be highlighted if you click "Debug" on the error dialog). What are the values of the variables at that point?

Comment: Most likely cause is there isn't a sheet called setup or MD1.

Comment: The error occurs at this line:

Comment: @sean  The error occurs at this line:`Sheets(sh).Range(ce) = Sheets("MD1").Range("A" & r)` I just tried to use the Quick Watch function to find out the values of the different variables at this point, and for all variables it says <Out of context>. @rory: There is a sheet called setup and also a sheet called MD1

Comment: What is the value of `sh` and `ce`?

Comment: @Rory: Is that you? I can't believe it! You in SO? :D

Comment: @user3845702: if you are sure that the values of `sh` and `ce` are correct then try this `Sheets(Trim(sh)).Range(Trim(ce)) = Sheets("MD1").Range("A" & r)`

Comment: @siddharth how can I see the values of `sh` and `ce`

Comment: Try the above suggestion first and then we will take it form there?

Comment: @siddharth even if I insert your code I get the error message. How can I see the values of the variables?

Comment: Check the values of `c14` and `c15`

Comment: @user3845702, above the line, put `msgbox "sh=" & sh` and `msgbox "ce=" & ce`. you will get a popup that tells you what the values are

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes it is me. Why so surprised? ;) Haven't "seen" you in ages!

Comment: @Rory: Well, I have been here all the time since I left EE :)